# Selenium Webdriver not working in AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.

(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /home/ubuntu/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Stacktrace: #0 0x5566bf874e23

#1 0x5566bf59d7a7

#2 0x5566bf5c850a

#3 0x5566bf5c5a25

#4 0x5566bf605d92

#5 0x5566bf6053af

#6 0x5566bf`
```

I get the above error only in server, it works perfectly fine in local. My local code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')  
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

i get the error at the "driver" step in server.
Any solutions ??

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue- trying to run selenium on an EC2 instance. It's because the client is headless, so there is a rendering issue. I found the answer in the stack below:

[how to make selenium and chromium work on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119570/how-to-make-selenium-and-chromium-work-on-ubuntu)

Need to use pyvirtualdisplay to emulate a browser. Make sure you have Xvfb installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing `google-stable-chrome` on AWS EC2 worked for me. I have tried @timothymux solution but problem persists. So, try following steps:

- `cd /tmp`
- `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
- `sudo apt-get -f install`

this will store the goole chrome to the /tmp directory and then you can simply install it by following the commands.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/510063/1766426)