# Selenium - chrome Driver fail to start in background (without a start-up window)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and trying to initialize the Chrome driver to start without a start up window.

```
ChromeOptions options= new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-startup-window");
//I tried this line also: options.addArguments("--silent-launch");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Capabilities);
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the binary first from selenium website, download binary according to your specifications:-

```
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.19/
```

Now set below code so selenium script will know the path of your binary

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
```

So the code should be like this:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options= new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-startup-window");
//I tried this line also: options.addArguments("--silent-launch");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the flag you are looking for is --headless
This feature has just been implemented in chrome 57

--no-startup-window is used for hosting background apps, see [this page](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and as mentioned in the other answers doesn't launch a window which is why the webdriver can't talk to it.

--headless does launch a window, but doesn't make it visible.

Comment: Yes it does, it isn't documented that well yet, but it works (=

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to download a file using headless chrome?

Comment: I don't see why not, but haven't tried it. so I would say, try! And let us know ;-)

Comment: I am trying to download file which has link inside iFrameReport. Without headless mode, chrome is downloading the file but in headless mode, it si failing to find tag for iFrameReport. i verified in page_source, tag is there.

Comment: Ah that seems to be a known bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471151/chromium-chrome-headless-file-download-not-working. Too bad. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942322/headless-browser-testing-with-download-functionality) are some solutions with other browsers, but you've probably already found those.. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Selenium and trying to initialize the Chrome driver to start without a start up window.

According to Selenium GitHub ([Strange error, chromedriver with --no-startup-window](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5351)), Selenium requires JavaScript and Chrome window to work:

> Much like --disable-javascript, the chromedriver will not work if you use --no-startup-window.
>   It needs to launch a window to establish the connection with the AutomationProxy.