# How to configure Selenium web driver to start a chrome browser in the background

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and trying to configure the Chrome driver to start in the background, that is I don't want the window to take focus. The idea is that running the test suite does not disrupt my flow when I am coding. I want the window focus to remain on the actual code editor, not on the newly created chrome window.

So I found this answer: [Selenium - chrome Driver fail to start in background (without a start-up window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009963/selenium-chrome-driver-fail-to-start-in-background-without-a-start-up-window/33010955#33010955)

But it uses Java. I need a Ruby solution.

I am currently using the Chrome driver as this:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

How can I achieve what I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating from the original Java, you just need to add the startup argument to your `Capabilities` and pass that to the new Driver instance:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--no-startup-window" ]})

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,
     :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
end
```

**Reference:** https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: Excellent, it does start the chrome browser in the background. Nonetheless, Capybara doesn't start to run the tests unless I click on the browser and give it focus. Is there a way to fake it?

Comment: How about this alternate approach? I can update answer if this works for you: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/10#issuecomment-132606226

Comment: I think I will just use a headless browser, and switch to selenium when I need to debug something. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nerian Selenium (Chrome driver to be exact) [doesn't support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43063728/2444725) Chrome browser in `--no-startup-window` mode.