# How to enable Download file in Headless Chrome in the latest Chrome Driver Ver: 2.40

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

My code works fine when `setHeadless(false)` is set, but not in headless mode.
I searched in lot of places and nothing helped me. [This issue was logged in Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5159), but is still in the "open" state. I'm using Java Selenium.

Note: I tried all the possible code which is already posted in https://stackoverflow.com 
Took screenshots and checked the behaviour also, it's moving and clicking the export icon link, but file is not downloading.

My code is below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "./Driver/chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setHeadless(true);

options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

options.addArguments("window-size=1600x900");

HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
chromePrefs.put("browser.setDownloadBehavior", "allow");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);  

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);     
driver.get(Url);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement export = driver.findElement(By
        .xpath("//*[@id='cssmenu1']/li[1]"));

try {
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(export).build().perform(); 
    act.click(export).build().perform();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: what is your chromedriver version and google chrome version. i didn't understand what you meant by Chrome version 40

Comment: Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 
ChromeDriver Version 2.40

Comment: Anybody having solutions??

Comment: this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471151/chromium-chrome-headless-file-download-not-working

Comment: Hi Prany, 
I tried all those steps mentioned in that link.Still not working..

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work for me after the driver was instantiated.

```
    var paramList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    paramList.Add("behavior", "allow");
    paramList.Add("downloadPath", GlobalConfig.DownloadsDirectoryPath);
    driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", paramList);
```

Using these packages:
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver v2.35.0
Selenium.WebDriver v3.10.0
Appium.WebDriver v4.0.0.1-beta
Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121

Comment: What is the Java equivalent?