# Protractor Headless Chrome unable to download file

Tags: typescript, download, protractor, headless

I'm trying to download a file using Protractor and Headless Chrome.  The test downloads the file successfully when running non-headless.

My protractor.conf.js has these capabilities set up:

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
  'args': ['no-sandbox', 'disable-setuid-sandbox', 'headless'],
  'prefs': {
    'download': {
      'prompt_for_download': false,
      'default_directory': '/tmp'
    }
  }
}
```

The way I am trying to download the file is by clicking a button in the UI.  Do you know of a solution to get headless file downloads to work, or can I provide additional information?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [bug with chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471151/chromium-chrome-headless-file-download-not-working/42583255#42583255). There some workarounds listed [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c80) but unfortunately none for typescript

Comment: After looking at it again there is a user who claims to have a working javascript snippet [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c141). You may be able to test that out.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
chromeOptions: {
  'args': [
    '--headless',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--test-type=browser',
    '--disable-extensions',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-infobars',
    '--window-size=1920,1080',
    //'--start-maximized'
     "--disable-gpu",
  ],
    prefs: {    
        'download.default_directory': 'C:\\downloads',
        'download.prompt_for_download':false,
        'download.directory_upgrade':true,
        "safebrowsing.enabled":false,
        "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection":true
      },
},
```