# Download img/png mime type , casperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having a casperJS script to trigger an image download on a button click. I have clicked the button, and the resouce.recived has a file of type image/png. How do I download that and save ? When I tried 
`download(resource, "something.png);` 
I get to download HTML(source code of the page) and not the desired image. 
Relevant segment of my code :

```
var dFile = casper.on('page.resource.received', function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        return;
    }
    if(resource.contentType.indexOf('image') >= 0)
    {
        console.log(resource.status);
        console.log(resource.contentType);
    }
    console.log("Downloading");
    casper.download(resource, "test011.png");

    dFile = resource;
    return dFile;
});
```

I've had a look at this, [downloading a file that comes as an attachment in a POST request response in PhantomJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144252/downloading-a-file-that-comes-as-an-attachment-in-a-post-request-response-in-pha) and tried implementing the solution, but doesn't seem to work. I'm new to Casper and JavaScript as well. Please let me know how to go about this. Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried [PhantomJS's File System module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)? There is a nice method for writing to files `fs.write(path, content, 'w');` and it should work in CasperJS.